# Python Multithreading Execute Threads In Order with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe, performance

Is there a way to **execute threads in a specific order**? I am familiar with the commands ".wait()" and ".notifyAll()", however it does not seem to work when all threads are targeting to a single function. The code below should write the csv file in this order: df1, df2, df3, df4.

---

```
import threading
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2","col3"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2","col3"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2","col3"])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["col1","col2","col3"])


def function(df):
    ###webscraping, compile web data to dataframe
    df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(df1,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(df2,))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(df3,))
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(df4,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
```

---

I want all dataframes to **wait inside "function()" until they can execute in order**. With multithreading, **threads like to "race each other" and can fall out of order executed**. Although multithreading is a good performance enhancing tool, its' downfall comes into play when order matters.

*Example of Simplicity:* If thread 4 finishes compiling its' dataframe, it needs to wait for the first 3 threads to compile its' corresponding dataframe and upload to the csv file until thread 4 can upload.

As always, thanks in advance!!

Comment: you might want to check out [dask.dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html) - something like this could be accomplished with dask pretty easily and if you were writing to parquet files or another format which supported parallel writes you could write in parallel too.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem in a clean way, you probably want to be using `concurrent.futures` instead of `threading`, hopefully you're on python3.2+.

To do so, you want to create a list of your arguments to the function in the order you need them to write `arglist = [df1, df2, ...]`, and then do something like

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(arglist)) as ex:
    results = ex.map(function, arglist)
for res in results:
    res.to_csv(..., mode='a')
```

To be honest, you should really try to use `concurrent.futures` for everything related to threading or multiprocessing.

It appears I read the question wrong the first time. I'll leave my previous answer here for people who google

> You can use a lock (see
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects), and
> then call `lock.acquire()` before writing to csv and then
> `lock.release()` afterwards. This will do exactly what you want.
>
> Although in my opinion this is not ideal, instead I would suggest
> returning the dataframes from each thread and just writing them all at
> the end.
>
> Your code would simply look like ``` lock = threading.Lock()
>
> def function(args):
> # web stuff
> with lock:
> df.to_csv(...) ```

Comment: Actually I think I may have read your question wrong, did you actually want to guarantee that the first thread wrote its dataframe first, then second one second etc. Then you definitely just want to return the dataframes and do it after

Comment: Yes, I wanted to guarantee that thread one would write, then 2, then 3, then 4. Are you saying I should use .join()? Cause wouldn't the program not be able to tell them apart if I use return and threading is still happening?

Comment: Also, I have prerequisites that take place. If I did .join() I would need to redo those prerequisites which would not be an option for this program needs to be as efficient as possible

Comment: Your insight about adding lock.aquire() and lock.release() would solve the problem I had of potential data overlap! That deserves an upvote from me. However, if there is a way to write to the output file in order without returning values, that would be excellent and deserving of the correct answer. I want to be able to execute this "chronological order upload" within "function()" if at all possible. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: My solution to this is super unclean, and I'm sure there is a better way, but if you passed the next thread in to each, so that (for example) call for the second one as `function(df2, t1)` then you would be able to simply type `t1.join()` above the `.to_csv()` and then just have to do this for all of them. If you actually only have 4 threads this will be easy to write hard-coded style. But if you have lots it might get a little ugly (although not too bad). Importantly, you'll need to pass None to the first one and actually have a check `if thread_input is not None: thread_input.join()`

Comment: I will say having any file input output inside of threads or processes should immediately make your race condition eyes go crazy, the reason I answered your initial question the way I did is that there was a much bigger problem in your code than just the ordering in that multiple consumer would be trying to write to a single file, which would not have been good.